# How to filter with multiple parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm building an app in which users submit posts, then tag them with the year, location, and military unit they were in. On my index page, I'd like to have 3 dropdowns for year location and military unit, and when a user specifies different values in the dropdowns, the index filters through only posts with those parameters. However, I've failed over and over.

Here's my Posts controller:

```
    def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @posts = @posts.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
    @posts = @posts.unit(params[:unit]) if params[:unit].present?
    @posts = @posts.year(params[:year]) if params[:year].present?
    end
```

My index view:

```
    <h1>All Posts</h1>
    <%= form_tag 'search', method: 'get' do %>
    <%= select :location, options_for_select(countries) %>
    <%= select :year, Time.now.year.downto(1900).to_a %>
    <%= select :unit, options_for_select(["army", "navy"]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "filter" %>
    <% end %>

</p>
<ul id="posts">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<li>
<%= link_to post.id, post_path(post) %>
</li>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>
</ul>
```

And my Posts model:

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_attached_file :image
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type =>     ["image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png"]
end
```

With it like it is right now, the error I'm receiving is "NoMethodError in Posts#index" : "undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass". The highlighted line is from the view:

```
<%= select :location_id, options_for_select(countries) %>
```

Thanks for any help with this. I've searched and not found very much that has helped.

EDIT: countries comes from the following helper:

```
    module CountriesHelper


    def countries
    [
     "Afghanistan",
     "Aland Islands",
     "Albania",
     "Algeria",

#truncated for space

      "Western Sahara",
      "Yemen",
      "Zambia",
      "Zimbabwe"
    ]

    end
    end
```

Comment: What is `countries`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: It's a helper that's just an array of country names.

Comment: Please update your post with that helper code.

Comment: Sure, just did that.

Comment: You posted that your error reporting on this line `<%= select :location_id, options_for_select(countries) %>` but you have `<%= select :location, options_for_select(countries) %>` in your form. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The select array needs to be formatted like this:

```
def countries
    [
     ["Afghanistan","Afghanistan"],
     ["Aland Islands","Aland Islands"],
     ["Albania","Albania"],
     and so on
.
.
.
    ]
```

**Then to use the select options in a search per your example snippet:**

```
<%= select_tag :search, options_for_select(countries), prompt: "Choose a country", class: 'your_css_class_here' %>
```

There might be some other issues, but this will set up the helper array properly. Let me know what happens and I can add to my answer.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score -3):

Where is the countries variable coming from?  It's a nil which mean it's not set.

I'm not a super ruby coder but this looks backwards to me too.

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
@posts = @posts.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
@posts = @posts.unit(params[:unit]) if params[:unit].present?
@posts = @posts.year(params[:year]) if params[:year].present?
end
```

I think it would be more like

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
   if params[:location].present?
       @posts = @posts.location(params[:location]) 
   end
   if params[:unit].present?
      @posts = @posts.unit(params[:unit]) 
   end
   if params[:year].present?
      @posts = @posts.year(params[:year])
   end
end
```